# Is there a down side to using a struct as input to a method?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I'm no expert, but I'm trying to understand if there's a flaw in my logic here. I'm pretty sure it won't take long to have it pointed out if so!

Instead of defining several parameters on a common method, why not simply have a structure as the single input parameter?  If each parameter is defined separately and another parameter is added or one is removed, this requires maintenance on every piece of code that calls that method.  If a structure was used, then none of the calling code would break, surely?  If some code in future required an extra parameter but legacy code didn't, I can add that parameter to the existing list and the legacy code remains untroubled.

As an example: I'm looking at a company where there are multiple websites/projects (to clarify from my original post, which said 'products' and could be misinterpreted as physical products) that need to interface with payment gateways.  Depending on the customer location, up to five different payment gateways might be called to process the customer payment.

Currently each one of these multiple products has its own implementation of the payment processing, complete with checking of returned parameters from the gateway.  I find this confusing and, well, plain wrong and although there isn't really the time or resource at present to rewrite everything from scratch, I think a relatively quick fix would be to create a new "payments" class project which had a defined set of parameters.

As far as I'm concerned, the front end should only do something as simple as call a method that is "make a payment of x in currency y in country z" and expect a success/fail flag & optional message that clarifies any failure in return.  This way, every product the company has will share the same payment processing.

Now parameter wise, currently the requirement for input would only be amount, currency & country (no, you can't always infer currency based on customer location before someone suggests it!).  And for a return it would only be a Boolean success/fail and a message explaining the reason for failure.  However it's possible that extra parameters will be required - both for in and out - in future and without wanting to break the existing calls to the method, it would appear sensible to simply use a simple structure, e.g.:

```
 struct inParams
 {
     public decimal amount;
     public string currency;
     public string country;
 };

 struct outParams
 {
     public bool success;
     public string message;
 };

    public outParams makePayment(inParams ip)
    {
        //...code goes here
    }
```

Is this a "Bad Thing" to do code-wise or is it acceptable practice?  If anyone thinks that it is better to have the parameters defined in the method signature individually, can you please explain why that would be better than my suggestion to use a simple structure please?

---

In response to "oɔɯǝɹ"

I don't really see that the issues you've raised are that serious though.

For example a sample call would be something like:

```
       PaymentProcessor pp = new PaymentProcessor();
       ppInParams ppIn = new ppInParams();
       ppIn.amount = 100;
       ppIn.currency = "USD";
       ppIn.country = "USA";

       ppOutParams ppOut = pp.makePayment(ppIn);
       if (!ppOut.success)
       {
           //check error message, handle error, display message
       }
       else
       {
           //display confirmation message to user, update account log
       }
```

Your point: `This leads to not very discoverable code` is hard to justify in the face of such simplicity as shown above, surely?

`Users need to add extra boiler plate code just to instantiate your parameter struct.` - well, yes, but it's not a major ballache to add a line of code for each parameter, is it?

`You will need to manage heaps of parameter structs. Two for every method.
    -How are you even going to name them?
    -In case you're thinming, I know, I'll just reuse them, then you've made your problem worse. Whats gonna happen when a single method using a struct need another parameter?`

I don't see the problem here either.  I have a single "paymentProcessor" class in which I have "ppInParams" and "ppOutParams" and they are contained within the class itself - to me, a perfectly logical place to put them as they relate directly to that class.

Your final point : `And in particular, your return type struct smells funny to me. Do you expect that every caller will inspect the boolean result? And what should i do with the message? Log it? show it? Have you not heard of structured exception handling?` seems bizarre to me and I don't understand the point you're trying to make. One million percent YES I expect every caller to check the boolean response as that's what tells them if the payment was a success or not!  This is the whole point of simplifying the call like this surely?  As the error handling is different depending on which web site has called the "makepayment" method, then again it makes perfect sense to me to handle the error back in the calling code.

Comment: What about customers that are using multiple payment sources for one order/product? It is common problem where payment comes from multiple accounts.

Comment: @StarPilot - that doesn't happen in this case.  These customers will pay in one go for their account balance/subscription.

Comment: @TheMook You may not agree with me (and you don't have to!), however, i get the feeling that no valid answer will make you change your mind here. Why did you even ask this question then?

Comment: I'm perfectly willing to change my mind as long as someone comes up with a reasonable argument for doing so.  I'm yet to see anything that convinces me that it's a "bad thing" and seems to actually come more down to preference and/or circumstance as far as I can tell?

Answer (score 3):

Products should not include payment processing.  Payment processing does not describe an attribute or action of `Product` it describes an action *on a* `Product`.  You likely need a `Payment` object which can be loosely based on your `inParams` struct:

```
class Payment {
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}
```

The `Country` property is interesting.  If knowing where the order was placed is important the Order came from a single location so `Country` should belong to `Order`.  However, if knowing which country each payment came from is important then `Country` should belong to `Payment`.  That is up to you.  I included `Country` in `Order`.

You will also need an `Order` object to group the `Payment` and `Products`.  Notice the `Order` object accepts an interface `IPaymentProcessor` as a constructor argument.  You can implement different payment processing behavior by passing a different implementation of the `IPaymentProcessor` interface into the `Order` object.  You can apply your business logic to figure out which concrete implementation should be sent to the `Order` constructor.  The important part of this is you will never need to go alter your `Order` or `Payment` classes to change the payment processing behavior.

```
class Order {
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    private IPaymentProcessor paymentProcessor;

    public Order(IPaymentProcessor paymentProcessor) {
        this.paymentProcessor = paymentProcessor;
    }

    void MakePayment(Payment payment) {
        this.paymentProcessor.ProcessPayment(payment);
    }
}
```

If you will never accept multiple Payments on an Order you can change the `ICollection<Payment> Payments` to `Payment Payment`.

IPaymentProcessor interface:

```
interface IPaymentProcessor {
    void ProcessPayment(Payment payment);
}
```

Remember structs are value types and will be copied when they are passed as a parameter to a method.  Classes are references types and only the reference (32 or 64 bit value based on the computer's word size) is passed by value to a method.  It looks like a class is better in the situation, especially if you anticipate the object to grow.

UPDATE AFTER COMMENT:

Well that certainly changes how I read your question!  I think much of the answer still applies so I will leave it.  Using the logic above I would implement an `OrderProcessor` Service that would accept `Order` objects and invoke their `ProcessPayment` method (and whatever other logic is required).  You still inject the `IPaymentProcessor` interface based on the rules of the system (where the order originated).  Alternatively, if chunks of the order process are similar then consider making `IPaymentProcessor` into a base class `PaymentProcessor` where you can override specific behaviors in the base class when needed.  There are lots of ways to implement this but the main idea I am trying to convey is this is an excellent case for polymorphism and this is just an example of how you could construct a basic architecture using that principle.

Comment: Thanks for the response - reading through this now. To clarify, I meant "product" as a generic term for web projects, sorry!  The company has various web projects/sites that are its products and they each need access to a payment system to allow people to pay for PHYSICAL products and services!

Comment: I really appreciate the thought and effort that's gone into this response, but (due to my lack of clarity in my original post) I don't think it's really addressed the point I'm looking at. There are already interfaces (and abstract classes)  in use in the various systems, but I'm trying to look at a single unifying "payments" class library that can be easily included in all projects and, put simply, the ONLY thing it needs to do is take in a few basic parameters and spit out a "success/fail" boolean and message if it failed. the calling code can handle any issues raised by the payment process.

Answer (score 3):

There can't be strict rules whether to wrap multiple input parameters into some class/structure or pass them individually. Everything depends on your particular situation.

Consider the following example (rather silly, just to show an idea):

```
public void makePayment(decimal amount, string currency, ILog logger)
{
    //...code goes here
}
```

Looking on the input parameters, it is obvious that `amount` and `currency` could have *semantic relationship* between each other. So, it's reasonable to wrap them into separate class `Payment`. But `ILog` is not related to `Payment` by no means. It's just a logger.

You could refactor your method to be like this:

```
public void makePayment(Payment payment, ILog logger)
{
    //...code goes here
}
```

The main idea that you should not *artificially* combine input parameters. You should combine them guided by their *semantic*. Then there are more chances that you will be able to reuse your classes in other places. Plus, do not forget about readability - it's easier to understand a meaning of your method if you have clear separation of semantically different dependencies.

As for output parameters, there is no much choice - you could return only one parameter (not considering ref/out arguments here). So, sure, it's OK to wrap multiple parameters into a separated class, but it's important to name it according to it's meaning: in your example it could be named, say, `PaymentResult`.

Comment: I agree with much of this, thanks.  However you seem to be artificially creating a situation that I haven't suggested - I have no interest in adding logging ability to the payment class, it will ONLY be used for payment, never anything else so parameters will always be relevant (logically and semantically).  I'm not intending violating the SRP, just putting all payment code in one place with simple in/out parameters.

Answer (score 0):

**Breaking changes gonna break;**

Consider what happens when you need to update the payment method to add another required parameter. For example, since currency exchange rates can change and you're making international payments, you discover that you need to add a date parameter, to determine the correct exchange rate.

The exchange rate at opening of market is taken as the desired value. This is a mandatory requirement, leaving that out will introduce a whole lot of trouble and bleeds money. So your struct becomes:

```
struct inParams
{
    public decimal amount;
    public string currency;
    public string country;
    public DateTime paymentDate;
};
```

'Great' you think, since you didn't break change the interface. But since this is a mandatory value, omitting this value, will throw an `ArgumentNullException`.

Only problem is, all the users of your interface still need to update their code!

Comment: This is only true if a mandatory parameter is added.  Otherwise the null value would be handled in the  payment method for the calling code that isn't affected by any non-mandatory additional parameters.  In contrast, if I add optional parameters to the method signature in future then I have to declare them optional and add code to handle them anyway so I'm no better off that I can see.  The way I'm considering, I have a simple "ppInParams" struct that keeps the method signature clean and doesn't result in method calls like `makePayment(100.00,"USD","USA",2.3,"Donkey","Barack Obama",3.44"`

Answer (score -1):

Besides my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28098509/62662), i think this is a bad practice.

- This leads to not very discoverable code. Editors, IDE's and IntilliSense are tuned to regular parameter passing.
- Users need to add extra boiler plate code just to instantiate your parameter struct.
- You will need to manage heaps of parameter structs. Two for every method.

  - How are you even going to name them?
  - In case you're thinming, `I know, I'll just reuse them`, then you've made your problem worse. Whats gonna happen when a single method using a struct need another parameter?
- And in particular, your return type struct smells funny to me. Do you expect that every caller will inspect the `boolean` result? And what should i do with the message? Log it? show it? Have you not heard of structured exception handling?

**TL,DR;** You might get a little advantage locally (which i don't see), but it requires a whole lot extra work calling functions like this. Since there are likely more callers of a method, than the method itself, you should make it ia easy as possible to call your method.

Comment: I've added a section in the original post to address your points.  TL;DR: I don't agree with all you say and I don't even think some points you make are valid. I may, of course, be wrong.